# find out if the month is the consective month in javascript

Tags: javascript

Want to compare the initial month with the month list and find out if the month is consecutive or non consecutive.

```
Jan - the initial value
All the months below should be compared with Jan.
Feb. - Feb is the consecutive month when compared to Jan -- so it should be marked as Yes
April - Not a consecutive month when compared to Jan - so it should be marked No.
```

```
Jan 
Feb - consecutive month
April - Not a consecutive month
```

I am wondering if i can use getMonth() to get the index of the month and compare the index and decide if the month is consecutive or not. Can it be verified using the index?

```
JavaScript Date getMonth()
getMonth() returns the month (0 to 11) of a date.
```

Comment: So, you have a **string** that represents a month and you want to check if that month is the next one after the current one. Is that the case ?

Comment: Yes, you can use `getMonth()`. Your situation is unclear though... you say that _Jan_ (is) _the initial value_ — is the value the String "Jan", or is it a Date object where `getMonth()` would return `0`? If you have two Date objects you can compare `otherDate.getMonth() - firstDate.getMonth() === 1`

Comment: i have the values like these  eg: Jan 01 2023 , 02 Feb 2023, 04 April 2023, convert that to a Date object before comparing for consecutive months. Date objects basically.

Comment: You could make Date objects from those strings and use getMonth, or you could make your own array and compare array indices.

Comment: You don't have to *wonder* if you can use `getMonth()`, you can *try* it

Answer (score 0):

You can turn your text month names into Date objects, then compare the values of `.getMonth()` to see if they are consecutive.

Say you have two month strings

```
let firstMonth = "Jan";
let otherMonth = "Feb";
```

You can make dates out of these with the Date constructor by making them into a valid date string...

```
let firstDate = new Date(firstMonth + " 5, 2020");
let otherDate = new Date(otherMonth + " 5, 2020");
```

The addition of `" 5, 2020"` turns each into something like "Jan 5, 2020" — what is added isn't important, as long as it creates a valid date string and is consistent.  I'd even define `const dateSuffix = " 5, 2020"` then use `new Date(firstMonth + dateSuffix)`

Now that you have two date objects you can use getMonth

```
let consecutive = otherMonth.getMonth() - firstMonth.getMonth() === 1;
```

There's a problem with the fact that "Dec" -> "Jan" should be consecutive, but the subtraction doesn't produce `1` -- but it's simple to add a check for that ... the difference is `-11`

Here's a snippet that demonstrates this:

```js
const dateSuffix = ' 5, 2020';

// This function is wrong because it doesn't handle the
// fact that "Dec" -> "Jan" is consecutive
function isConsecutiveWrong(month1, month2)
{
    const d1 = new Date(month1 + dateSuffix);
    const d2 = new Date(month2 + dateSuffix);
    
    const isConsecutive = d2.getMonth() - d1.getMonth() === 1;
    return isConsecutive;
}

// Includes handling the "Dec" -> "Jan" transition as consecutive
function isConsecutive(month1, month2)
{
    const d1 = new Date(month1 + dateSuffix);
    const d2 = new Date(month2 + dateSuffix);
    
    const m1 = d1.getMonth();
    const m2 = d2.getMonth();
    
    const isConsecutive = m2 - m1 === 1   ||
                          m2 - m1 === -11;
    return isConsecutive;
}


let firstMonth = 'Jan';
let otherMonth = 'Feb';
let thirdMonth = 'Oct';
let december   = 'Dec';


console.log(`${firstMonth} -> ${otherMonth}, consecutive? ` +
            isConsecutive(firstMonth, otherMonth));

console.log(`${firstMonth} -> ${thirdMonth}, consecutive? ` +
            isConsecutive(firstMonth, thirdMonth));

console.log(`${december} -> ${firstMonth}, consecutive? ` +
            isConsecutive(december, firstMonth));
```